# Не работает html-импорт

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Любыми методами, которые я не пробовал. И различные скрипты на JS/jQ, и через link rel="import" - оно просто не хочет работать, и всё. В чём может быть проблема?
Есть, допустим, такой вариант:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#includedContent").load("b.html");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="includedContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вроде бы ничего сложного. Но оно не работает.
Или вот ещё пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>What are HTML imports and how do they work</title>
    <link rel="import" href="/file.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
      var content = link.import.querySelector('#div');
      document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

То есть импортируется файл, и скрипт берёт из него определённый div по id. Но и это тоже не работает

Comment: Ошибки падают какие-нибудь?

Comment: Нет, без каких-либо ошибок

Comment: В первом случае в момент работы скрипта нужный div ещё не создан в DOM.

Во втором - что за странная конструкция ```link.import``` ?

Comment: Это нужно спрашивать у того, кто данный пример создавал

Comment: @ВикторКарев, [устаревшее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773925/2881286) да и раньше похоже только в хроме работало.

Comment: @LatexMoose, первый вариант работает. [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-goldstine-tmbqxw?file=/index.html)

Comment: Странно конечно. Я конечно могу попробовать ещё раз, но чёт не уверен

Comment: @LatexMoose, сравни чем твой код отличается от того, что в примере. Можешь добавить больше информации в вопрос. Например: как запускаешь, какая версия jquery, какая версия браузера (если в браузере запускаешь)?

Comment: Код ничем не отличался. Запускаю с диска в браузере (Firefox самой последней версии на стабильной сборке), версия jQ - 3.6

Comment: _Запускаю с диска в браузере_ - что у тебя в адресной строке?

Comment: До корневой папки русские символы присутствуют, и сама корневая папка тоже на русском названа

Comment: скопируй сюда что конкретно у тебя в адресной строке. Важен протокол.

Comment: С:/Documents/*папка на русском*/*папка на русском*/*корневая директория сайта на русском*

Comment: Протокол идет до `C:/` и заканчивается `//` но судя по пути он `file://`

Comment: Закрыл как дубликат: суть - чтобы работал ajax - нужен свой сервер. При запуске просто с файловой системы не будет работать.

Comment: В Github Pages AJAX будет работать?

Comment: да, так как для доступа ты будешь вводить `http`