# Не работат JS/jQ-скрипты при импорте HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

[Продолжая данную тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1415042/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-html-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82?noredirect=1&lq=1). Импорт HTML по коду ниже всё-таки удалось завести через .load

```js
$(function(){
$("класс или ид дива, куда выгрузится контент").load("ссылка на импортируемый html-файл");
});
```

Однако появилась другая проблема - ломающиеся после перезагрузки страницы скрипты из импортируемых html-файлов. В первый раз, когда запускаешь страницу, они работают нормально. После обычной перезагрузки (f5) они перестают срабатывать. Но если сделать чистую перезагрузку (ctrl+f5), то скрипты вновь начинают работать до последующей обычной перезагрузки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогли со стороны, но ответ я всё же напишу. Проблема заключалась в том, что сначала должны исполняться скрипты импорта, а уже потом всё остальное. Так как никаких ограничений по времени не стояло, то скрипты импорта могли исполняться позже остального фронтэнда, из-за чего последние не срабатывали и сайт "ломался". Решилось всё это дело путём оборачивания функций в **setTimeout()** с выставлением времени где-то в 500 мс, дабы скрипты точно выполнились позже импорта. Это также можно провернуть и через **callback**, но это более заморочисто, как по мне

```js
function name() { //название функции нужно дать обязательно
  //сюда вы пишите скрипт, который нужно исполнить
};
setTimeout(function () { //оборачиваем функции в setTimeout()
  name1();
  name2();
  namex();
}, 500); //вместо 500 можете вставить другое число мс
```